# Ubuntu crashing when idle

Tags: 14.04, crash

Sometimes when I let my computer idle for long periods of time (like I've gone to work or sleep), I come back to a blank screen that I can't wake up.  Pressing keys and moving the mouse does nothing.  If the num-lock LED is on, it turns off when I press a key and won't turn back on.  Ctrl-alt-F1 and ctrl-alt-backspace do nothing.  I can press the restart button on the computer and it restarts just fine.

It is set to turn the screen off when idle for 30 minutes, and usually comes back just fine after that time period. It is not set to suspend ever.  This is a fresh install, and all hardware except the hard drive and case were bought in the past couple weeks. (The hard drive is pretty old, and I am willing to replace it if I'm fairly confident that it's causing my problems)

Hardware:

- Gigabyte LGA 1150 Intel H81 HDMI/DVI/D-SUM USB3.0/SATA 6GBs Dual UEFI BIOS GA-H81M-HD2
- Gigabyte R7 260X GDDR5-1GB 2xDVI/HDMI/DP OC Graphics Card (GV-R726XOC-1GD)
- Crucial Ballistix Sport 4GB Single DDR3 1600 MT/s (PC3-12800) CL9 @1.5V UDIMM 240-Pin
- Memory Module BLS4G3D1609DS1S00
- Intel Pentium Processor G3220 3.0 GHz LGA 1150 BX80646G3220
- Corsair CX Series 430 Watt ATX/EPS Modular 80 PLUS Bronze ATX12V/EPS12V 384 Power
- Supply CX430M
- WDC WD5000AAKS-0

Any thoughts on where to start troubleshooting this issue?

Edit: Results of `glxinfo | grep OpenGL`:

```
OpenGL vendor string: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc.
OpenGL renderer string: AMD Radeon R7 200 Series
OpenGL core profile version string: 4.3.13084 Core Profile Context 14.301.1001
OpenGL core profile shading language version string: 4.40
OpenGL core profile context flags: (none)
OpenGL core profile profile mask: core profile
OpenGL core profile extensions:
OpenGL version string: 4.4.13084 Compatibility Profile Context 14.301.1001
OpenGL shading language version string: 4.40
OpenGL context flags: (none)
OpenGL profile mask: compatibility profile
OpenGL extensions:
```

Comment: What are the specifics of your graphics card and who made it? I know these problems are common with AMD and ATI cards.

Comment: The exact video card I bought: http://smile.amazon.com/gp/product/B00H707TI2/ref=oh_aui_detailpage_o02_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1

OpenGL vendor string: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc.
OpenGL renderer string: AMD Radeon R7 200 Series
OpenGL core profile version string: 4.3.13084 Core Profile

Comment: Hmmm... You said that when you press Ctrl+Alt+F1 nothing happens. The only problem with this is that once you press Ctrl+Alt+F1, you're no longer in X11 and thus this can't be a driver problem as the terminal and X11 use completely different drivers. Are you sure this isn't an issue with your monitor?

Comment: I have the computer on a KVM switch with a laptop.  When I have this issue, I can switch to the laptop just fine, and when I switch back it's still a blank screen.  When I reboot the computer it comes right back up, so I don't see how it could be a monitor problem.

Comment: I add this issue before, and I solved it by hitting the power button once: It wakes up the computer from deep sleep... maybe it's not this case though.

Comment: Make a note of the time when you plan leave your computer idle for longer and when you return to find it "frozen". After a reboot, look at the content of `/var/log/syslog`, `/var/log/pm-suspend.log`, and `/var/log/pm-suspend.log`. Isolate the entries relating to the noted time period and include them in your question (or a link to them). If you have set up SSH access, it may also be possible that your computer still responds to that, in which case you should save the output of `sudo dmesg` to a file and submit the relevant part like the other log files.